# Central OAuth2.0 Authorization on the Backend-Side using PHP and curl for Spotify Web API

Tags: php, api, curl, authorization, spotify

I am creating an application which aims at automatically creating Spotify Playlists in a central Spotify account (not the account of the end users).
I have set up this account and created the developer app for the secret and the client_id.

On the backend side, I am using PHP to authorize this central user, and it is working as long as I am logged in myself with that account.

Users that visit my website should be able to create playlists via that interface through the Spotify Web API without the need to authorize their account nor being logged in at all.

If I'm trying to open the same page on a separate device (without having any account logged in), it just gives me the following error:

`User not registered in the Developer Dashboard`

Is it somehow possible to perform this authorization process only on the backend side without the need for the user to authorize it?

Eventually, I want to send the playlist URL created in the central Spotify Account to the user who can open it in their own app or share with others, if they want to.

I try to avoid that multiple users must authorize for my app, since I don't need to access personal information from their account, anyways.

I used the 3-step process for authorization as described in this Stackoverflow Post: [Spotify oauth2 with PHP curl. How to get authorization code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866625/spotify-oauth2-with-php-curl-how-to-get-authorization-code)

If necessary, I will provide more information.

Do you have any idea, how I can implement this authorization process for the single account on the backend side, without the user even showing any authorization process of the Spotify Web API at all?

EDIT1: I am not trying to login on the behalf of my users, just automatically for my own account without the interactive login with Spotify. Is that even possible?

Comment: OAuth2.0 Authorization results in an access token you use to make API requests, so ... simply store that token for your "special account" somewhere.

Comment: You mean by using the refresh_token before the access token expires?
The problem is that it seems that I can use the token always only once, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I received [valuable feedback from the Spotify Developer Community](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/Central-OAuth2-0-Authorization-on-the-Backend-Side-using-PHP-and/m-p/5417864#M5271) that helped me finding a solution to the problem.

When you let the central Spotify account login to your app, you'll [get] an access_token (that will expire in 1 hour) and a `refresh_token`.

When the access_token of that account expires, let your server send a POST request to the Accounts service `/api/token` endpoint, but use the refresh_token in place of the access_token.

`A new access_token will be returned.`

A new refresh_token might be returned too. (I don't think that's even needed)

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/).